# how to get sum between two decimal values in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working with an app android studio - `mrate` is the rate for 1 km distance and `replacetext` is the distance between two points and replacing the (km) form the distance -  when distance value has decimal value (10.5 )then the system is getting an error

```
String mykm =dbDistance.getText().toString();

String mrate = dbRate.getText().toString();
System.out.println(mrate);

String replacetext;
replacetext = mykm.replace(" km", "");
System.out.println(replacetext);


//convert value into int
int x=Integer.parseInt(mrate);
int y=Integer.parseInt(replacetext);

//sum these two numbers
int z=x+y;

System.out.println(z);
```

Comment: the system is getting an error -> where is the stacktrace ?

Comment: 2018-11-08 12:20:19.005 17543-17543/net.atsuae.vehiclebooking I/System.out: 5
2018-11-08 12:20:19.005 17543-17543/net.atsuae.vehiclebooking I/System.out: 2.5
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2018-11-08 12:20:19.007 17543-17543/net.atsuae.vehiclebooking E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.atsuae.vehiclebooking, PID: 17543
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2.5"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
        at

Comment: you **obviously** can't store decimal values in `int` variable. As well as it is **obvious** that `10.5` can't be parsed into `int`.

Comment: NumberFormatException: For input string: "2.5". What Vladyslav said. Please Google your exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use BigDecimal objects for easy conversion and arithmetics

```
    BigDecimal decimal1 = new BigDecimal("1.024");
    BigDecimal decimal2 = new BigDecimal("52.232");
    BigDecimal decimal3 = decimal1.add(decimal2);
    BigDecimal decimal4 = decimal3.multiply(decimal1);
    String newValue = decimal4.toString();
```

BigDecimal is very powerful especially if you want precision with large decimal places or large numbers in general

Answer (score 1):

```
//convert value into int
int x=Integer.parseInt(mrate);
int y=Integer.parseInt(replacetext);
```

If you've got decimal values, use `Double` or `Float` instead of `Integer`

Comment: yes he have decimals java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2.5" at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)

Comment: Thank you very much. you save my day!